# Facing undefined symbols linker issue with Diab compiler when I type cast array of data from float to long long

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, long-long, wind-river-workbench

I wrote a small example code and executed in both GCC and DIAB compilers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float a[10];

    long long int b[10];
    int i;
    for (i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1.256*i;
        b[i] = (long long int)a[i];
        printf("%f\t%lld\n",a[i],b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output in GCC compiler is:

0.000000    0
1.256000    1
2.512000    2
3.768000    3
5.024000    5
6.280000    6
7.536000    7
8.792000    8
10.048000   10
11.304000   11

The issue in DIAB compiler is :

> dld.exe: warning: Undefined symbol '__asr64' in file
>   'sfpfftoll.o(C:\WINDRI~2\diab\580~1.0-3\PPCVLEES\libimpfp.a)' dld.exe:
>   warning: Undefined symbol '__lsl64' in file
>   'sfpfftoll.o(C:\WINDRI~2\diab\580~1.0-3\PPCVLEES\libimpfp.a)' dld.exe:
>   error: Undefined symbols found - no output written make.exe: ***
>   [..\output\bin\xxxxxxx.elf] Error 1

Is there any work around to convert array of floats to array of long long int? I tried using pointers but still facing the same linker issue.